# How to return from an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

My code looks like this:

```
myObject.myMethod('imageCheck', function () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onerror = function() {
        return false;

    };  
    image.onload = function() {
        return true;
    };
    image.src = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg';         
});
```

But, it doesn't work, assumedly because my returns only return from the anonymous function, not from the one called imageCheck. How can I rewrite this so that the whole function is returned as true or false?

Comment: What is myMethod and what is imageCheck?  Why are you returning something in a handler function for an async call?  That return data does not do anything.  You have to use the "continuation" style of programming for async.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use callbacks, for example:

```
myObject.myMethod('imageCheck', function () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onerror = function() {
        returnCallback(false);

    };  
    image.onload = function() {
        returnCallback(true);
    };
    image.src = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg';         
});

function returnCallback(bool){
    //do something with bool
}
```

Comment: Yup. That's definitely the way to go. In case you wanted to be pedantic you could apply true/false partially to returnCallback and avoid extra function definitions. This is more "functional" way to do the same thing. Either way works.

Comment: In this case, the myObject.myMethod is actually from a 3rd party library, so I have to ensure that that function returns true or false. How do I use this technique to do that?

Comment: Basically the myObject.myMethod('imagecheck',function () {} ); needs to return either true or false. If it wasn't an async check, I'd just finish with `return bool;`, but I can't work out how to wait until onerror or onload has fired, then return with the boolean. I might not understand this topic enough, so if that doesn't make sense, then I need to read up more on async stuff!

Comment: async cannot do a return. this is bc the js runs through the whole script even if it is not done yet, so when the async **is done** and it needs to do something, so the only way to _simulate_ a return is by making a callback fn

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I got in touch with the writer of the 3rd party script who suggested a different approach entirely! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RichBradshaw it would be awesome if you shared the different approach